# Passport.js redirects to |successRedirect: '/profile'| but req.isAuthenticated() returns false

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

The following code is a section of an app developed by Node.js + Express + Passport.js. A valid user gets redirected to `/profile` url (successRedirect), however the `req.isAuthenticated` returns false and also the `req.user` is `undefined`. I couldn't figure out what might be the cause:

```
app.post('/login',
    passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect: '/profile',// <-- a valid user gets redirected to `/profile`
        failureRedirect: '/',
        failureFlash: true
    })
);


app.get('/profile',function(req,res){    
    console.log('req.user: \n'+req.user)
    console.log('req.isAuthenticated(): '+req.isAuthenticated()) // <-- However, the `req.isAuthenticated()` returns false
    console.log('req.isAuthenticated: '+req.isAuthenticated)
    res.render('profile.ejs',{
        /*username: req.user.username*/ // <-- req.user is undefined
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On each route where authentication is needed you should apply passport.authenticate middleware i.e :

```
app.get('/profile', passport.authenticate('local'), (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.user);
  console.log(req.isAuthenticated());
}
```

see [Passport documentation](http://passportjs.org/docs)

Comment: I think this could have unintended side effects.My understanding is that passport.authenticate is authenticating a request when a user 1st submits a login form,but for subsequent routes this shouldn't need to be the case. An example of this can be seen here https://github.com/passport/express-4.x-local-example/blob/master/server.js by passports author.He then uses ensure-logged-in middleware to check the /profile route,that under the hood is checking req.isAuthenticated with some added redirect behaviour. https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-ensure-login/blob/master/lib/ensureLoggedIn.js