# Node.js Server with MongoDB Database + Passport : req.user is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, passport-local, passport.js

I'm currently working on a project including a chrome extension and a login. To verify if the User is logged in on my Server from the Chrome Extension, I have made a new route called /checkuserlogin. But whenever I try to retrieve the user object that is also received on other routes (where it works perfectly), I get "undefined". Using Passport to authenticate.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Did you call ``passport.authenticate`` middleware on your route ? See : http://stackoverflow.com/a/41426657/4712818

Comment: @MatthieuLemoine Thank you, that was my problem. I wasn't calling `passport.authenticate` on my /checkuserlogin route